# Querying the Target of a Linker Script?

Tags: c++, gnu, ld, dlopen, linker-scripts

I have some C++ code that is dlopening the "libm.so" library:

```
dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
```

Under RHEL7, this was a sym-link:

```
libm.so -> libm.so.6
```

Under RHEL9, this is now a linker script:

```
> cat libm.so
/* GNU ld script
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libm.so.6  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/libmvec.so.1 ) )
```

which means this dlopen() call fails because it cannot parse this linker script.

The only solution to this problem that I have found is to hard-code the library name to `dlopen("libm.so.6", ...")`. I am either looking for a way to query that number "6" so that this is not hard-coded in the source or to otherwise evaluate the linker script at build time to find the required target.

Comment: Honestly, changing it to libm.so.6 seems like a good choice. If the version changes the new library may well not be compatible (unlikely, I admit, with libm, but I could see it happening with some other library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am either looking for a way to query that number "6" so that this is not hard-coded in the source

There is nothing wrong with hard-coding this number on Linux (or other GLIBC-based systems). It has not changed in the last 20 years and is very unlikely to ever change.

> or to otherwise evaluate the linker script at build time to find the required target.

You can use `grep -q 'libm\.so\.6' $(gcc --print-file-name=libm.so)` to test that `libm.so.6` is *still* the right version and error out if it's not.

P.S. `g++` links with `-lm` by default; it's very likely that your `dlopen` does not serve any useful purpose.